# Creating Image Diagrams similar to JSON

Tags: json, image, diagram

I've seen it done in several books and such, so there has to be something that is generating them, or I'm just outright not seeing the tools in Visio, but I was wondering if anyone knows how to make diagrams similar to the ones commonly seen in regards to JSON.

Example Seen Here : http://www.json.org/object.gif

[image: Example]

Comment: Seee 'External Links' section here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_diagram

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- http://dotnet.jku.at/applications/Visualizer/
- http://www.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/~thiemann/haskell/ebnf2ps/
- http://karmin.ch/ebnf/index

It doesn't have anything to do with json, it just takes a grammar spec and renders it visually.